# WCF deserializing - choosing type in depends on some field - once and for all deciding this issue

Tags: c#, wcf, deserialization, xml-deserialization

Is it possible to help deserializer of `WCF` ?
I mean that in my soap messages I send some special field like:
`<someField>someValue</someField>`
And based on this `someField` I give a hint to WCF  deserializer what type it should deserialize ?

Comment: My suggestion is, don't do that. Don't try to use custom XML.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I think that you are right. On the client side it should be done. Hmm ?

Comment: What happens when you use no custom mechanisms at all? What does your app lack in that case?

Comment: In this case I must have over-model and in controller cast to subtype using `someField` attribute.

Comment: Then that's the answer.

Comment: I don't understand. What do you mean ?